# How to see the number of search return with Ag?

Tags: vimrc, search, the-silver-searcher

Is there anyway that I can see the number of result with `:Ag`

(attached) If somewhere I could see the number of return would be awesome. I can't find any reference for it on Internet. Thanks

My .vimrc setup: https://gist.github.com/houmanka/9790614407bcbed4e12d199b9bef32e8

[image]

After I do the search, in the quickfix window I type `:set errorformat` and I get this:

```
errorformat=%*[^"]"%f"%*\D%l: %m,"%f"%*\D%l: %m,%-G%f:%l: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once,%-G%f:%l: for each f
unction it appears in.),%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c:,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c\,,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c,%
-GIn file included from %f:%l,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:%c,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l\,,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l,%f:%l:%c:%m,%f(%l)
:%m,%f:%l:%m,"%f"\, line %l%*\D%c%*[^ ] %m,%D%*\a[%*\d]: Entering directory %*[`']%f',%X%*\a[%*\d]: Leaving directory %*[`']%f',%D
%*\a: Entering directory %*[`']%f',%X%*\a: Leaving directory %*[`']%f',%DMaking %*\a in %f,%f|%l| %m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:Ag` inserts its results into a so-called Quickfix window and, as for anything loaded there, an indication of the current result and total results will be displayed on the right side of the status line. See the `1/46` in your screen shot? That means you're currently on the first result out of a total of 46.

If you've already closed the Quickfix window then just by using the Quickfix navigation commands (`:cnext`, `:cc`, `:cfirst`, etc.) you'll see "*[current] of [total]*" prefixed to the (new) current result in the message area (command line).

Note, though, that all of the navigation commands can move the cursor. If you're still on the current result then `:cc` will display the position/total and result text without moving the cursor but if you've previously navigated away you can see the total while ensuring the cursor is not moved by using the nice solution @PeterRincker provides below: `:echo len(getqflist())`.

**Non-Vim Note:** Your result count will not be accurate because you have all those `||` lines in your `ag` output. This is caused by the `--noheading` flag. There's no reason for that to be there when feeding Quickfix. Remove it and the result count should be correct.

**Epilogue:** To save someone from reading the wall of comments below let me just sum up what else they cover beyond the previous paragraph: I discovered there is a variable in the `ag` plugin, `g:ag_prg`, that can be used to specify the exact `ag` command used for searches. It so happens that this is where `--noheading` originated so OP removed that flag and the problem of extra `||` lines went away. *And they lived happily ever after.*

Comment: Can also use `:cc` to show the current position in the quickfix list. See `:h :cc`

Comment: @PeterRincker Do you have to have previously closed the Quickfix window? As far as I can tell, it's a no-op when the window is still open.

Comment: I never noticed that. You are correct if the Quickfix window is open then `:cc` does nothing. I typically don't open the window, so I didnt really notice. I guess you could do `echo len(getqflist())`

Comment: Great, you saved me from having to figure it out myself. Thanks. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @BLayer `See the 1/46 in your screen shot` indicates that there is 46 lines in the Quickfix window. There are only 23 results. @PeterRincker `:echo len(getqflist())` returns the number of lines in the Quick fix window not the number of the results. If you look in the screenshot you will see after each result we have `||`. If I can get rid of them, then method that you suggested works.

Comment: Unless the input format is bad Quickfix will have one result per line. If `ag` is feeding improperly formatted lines to Quickfix then that's not a Vim issue. But let's see if we can figure things out. Where are the `ag` flags coming from? Are you adding `--column --nogroup --noheading` yourself or is the plugin. Because they are not right. They cause trouble when I try it myself. You can't use any flags you want, only those that don't make the formatting non-compliant with the pattern you get with `:set errorformat?`

Comment: Looks like `--noheading` is the offending flag. It's inserting empty lines between searched files. There's no reason you should need that with Quickfix so remove it and you should be good.

Comment: @BLayer I am not using `--noheading` or any flag. I just type `:Ag raise` `raise` is the search param. I have added my `.vimrc` to the question.

Comment: @MrH If you're not adding it then the plugin is. It's right there on the status line! Try it yourself. Feed `ag` output manually into `vim`...same effect as the plugin: `vim -q <(ag --noheading other_args)`. Then try again after removing the flag. The `||`-only lines go away. (Note: If you don't see QF window after vim launch do `:copen`.)

Comment: @BLayer you are right, then I don't know why it is adding `||` I have put my `.vimrc` and everything else about my vim, however there is nothing there that indicates and predefined options for `:Ag`.

Comment: @BLayer I accept your answer and open a new thread to see if someone knows why my `:Ag` adds options automatically - How does this sound?

Comment: @MrH If you give me a pointer to the Ag plugin's site I can take a quick look at the code. If I don't find anything your plan sounds good.

Comment: @MrH It's an issue with the plugin: https://github.com/rking/ag.vim/issues/156 Note that the plugin has the following in big bold text at the top of its README: **Deprecated: See this comment for more info. Maybe try ack.vim as an alternative.**

Comment: Certainly take note of what Rich has pointed out but I'm curious what value you see with `:echo g:ag_prg`. It's possible the flag has been added there or that you may be able to workaround the issue Rick linked to (the recommended setting is `/path/to/ag --vimgrep` ... or it may not be set at all).

Comment: @BLayer so when I did `:echo g:ag_prg` I got `ag --column --nogroup --noheading`

Comment: Well, there you go. That's the cause. Override it without the `--noheading` (`:let g:ag_prg ="ag ..."`). It's also possible that you can just unset the variable (i.e. `:unlet g:ag_prg`). That assumes the variable is optional and there is a hardwired default. (I think there is but don't hold me to it.)  Hopefully the bug that Rick mentioned won't stand in the way of one of these working.

Comment: @BLayer when I enter `:let g:ag_prg ="Ag raise"` nothing happens. ( Sorry, I am a newbee :) I put that straight in the vim not .vimrc.

Comment: Aha ok, so I did this and it work: `:let g:ag_prg = "Ag --column --nogroup"` then when I searched it gave me correct result \o/. Thanks mate for your help